# Play event does not work in HTML and Javascript

Tags: onmouseover, elementor

I have a problem with my javascript code, maybe you can find what I'm doing wrong. My Play() event does not do what I want.

I want to "re-make" a page of the ferrari site with an onmouseover event. This code is written with a HTML widget inside of elementor, maybe is that the reason why something isn't working.

Hope to hear from you!

My code;

```html
<div class="wrapper1" >
    <video id="Hvideo" width="320" height="240" preload="auto">
        <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJVHZR3KkjM" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <button id="Htext" onmouseover="Play()" onmouseout="Pause()">HVAC</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Htext=document.getElemenetById("Htext");
    var Hvideo=document.getElemenetById("Hvideo");
    
    function Pause(){
    Hvideo.pause();
    }
    
    function Play(){
    if(Hvideo.paused)
        Hvideo.play();
    }
</script>
```

**image**

[image: source]

[www.ferrari.com](http://www.ferrari.com)

Comment: i have tried your code it's giving `Errror : {
  "message": "TypeError: document.getElemenetById is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 17,
  "colno": 24
}`

Comment: Hello sutharp777, thank you for yor reponse. I see I made a type error. This is very silly, but thanks for the heads up! I shame myself... :-(

Comment: I do have an other question, how can you hide this video when the video isn't playing? i tried to add the code Hvideo.style.display = none, but in vain...

Comment: Welcome @Tim , happy to help you.